# Python Hash of First Image in MultiTIf

Tags: python, hash, md5, tiff

I am trying to get the hash MD5 of the first page of a Multi-TIf. I can get the hash of `A.tiff` below, but how to I read the hash of the first page only?

```
import hashlib

print(hashlib.md5(open('c:\\temp\\HASH\A.tif','rb').read()).hexdigest())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following might help. You can use the PIL library which has support for multi page TIFF files. With this you can use `seek()` to get the first page data:

```
import hashlib
from PIL import Image
from itertools import chain

img = Image.open(r'A.tif')
img.seek(0)

md5 = hashlib.md5()

if isinstance(img.getpixel((0,0)), int):
    md5.update(bytes(img.getdata()))
else:
    md5.update(bytes(chain.from_iterable(img.getdata())))

print(md5.hexdigest())
```

For most images this will provide a tuple, for monochrome / greyscale images it returns the value. These are all converted to bytes and run through  `md5.update()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot , but I'm getting an error at line 10        md5.update(struct.pack('3B', *p))
TypeError: pack() argument after * must be a sequence, not int

Comment: What version of Python are you using? This was tested on 2.7.9.

Comment: You could try the following instead `md5.update(struct.pack('3B', p[0], p[1], p[2]))`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I'm using 3.4 , But now I'm getting a different error   :  line 11, in <module>
    md5.update(struct.pack('3B', p[0], p[1], p[2]))
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Both variants work for me in Python 3.4.3. I am using PIL 1.1.7. e.g. `print(PIL.VERSION)`

Comment: What is displayed if you `print(p)` ?  You should see a 3 element tuple (possibly 4).

Comment: Print(p) give me 255 ,The Python Imaging Library 1.1.7 and Python 3.4.2.

Comment: I am guessing your image is one byte per pixel, I have modified it to support this.

Comment: md5.update(struct.pack('3B',p,p,p))   this work with the previous code,  ...... But I'm not sure why the hash is differrent if I extract the image seperately using irfvanView and read the hash using  print(hashlib.md5(open('c:\\temp\\HASH\A_page1.tif','rb').read()).hexdigest()) . the latest code give error ... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\Hashing\h1p.py", line 9, in <module>
    per_pixel = len(img.getpixel((0,0)))
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()  ...Thanks again

Comment: Could you give me a link to your test image? The hash might be different as this is hashing the pixel values, without any header information.

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/photo/ms28tbv9ce/A_online.html
http://www.4shared.com/photo/gX3sPH6cce/A1_online.html

Comment: Thanks, that was useful, it will hopefully work ok now. PIL switches to returning just an `int` rather than a `tuple` for monochrome images. Also should run much faster now.